# How many monospace characters fit horizontally and vertically in an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, monospace

I'm trying to find out how many monospace characters fit in an element (e.g. `div`), knowing the size and the `font-size`.

For instance I expected the result being:

```
{
   x: Math.floor(divWidth / fontSize)
 , y: Math.floor(divHeight / lineHeight)
}
```

But it seems that they are not right: for a font size `50px` and `width: 100px`, the expected answer would be `2`, but it is `3`:

```css
div {
    font-family: monospace;
    background: black;
    color: lightgreen;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
123
123
</div>
```

For the example above the answer should be:

```
{
   x: 3 // 3 chars horizontally
 , y: 1 // 1 char vertically
}
```

How to compute these values automatically?

```
var $div = $("div");
var divSize = {
    w: $div.width()
  , h: $div.height()
};
var fontSize = parseInt($div.css("font-size"));
```

Comment: font-size is the height of the font.

Comment: `font-size` refers to the glyph height not width. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust)

Comment: @njzk2 Ok, but then, why the text doesn't fit vertically?

Comment: @IonicăBizău: It does on my browser.

Comment: what is the `line-height` ? If it's not `1` will impact calcs.

Comment: you need to set `line-height` to 1

Comment: @njzk2 This is how it looks on my browser: http://i.imgur.com/zJTe2SU.png

Comment: @IonicăBizău default `line-height` is not 1 so there is additional vertical space applied in each line. set it to 1.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli How to get the absolute value of `line-height`? It just returns `"normal"` (`$(...).css("line-height")`).

Comment: Try `getComputedStyle(element).lineHeight`. This will return the line height in pixels. But be careful that changing the `font-size` on that element will alter its computed `line-height` if it was set to a relative unit (*`%`, `em` etc*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks for helpful comments. I created a jQuery plugin and posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built a jQuery plugin that does this:

```js
$.fn.textSize = function () {
    var $self = this;
    function getCharWidth() {
        var canvas = getCharWidth.canvas || (getCharWidth.canvas = $("<canvas>")[0])
          , context = canvas.getContext("2d")
          ;
        
        context.font = [$self.css('font-size'), $self.css('font-family')].join(' ');
        var metrics = context.measureText("3");
        return metrics.width;
    };

    var lineHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle($self[0]).lineHeight);
    return {
        x: Math.floor($self.width() / getCharWidth())
      , y: Math.floor($self.height() / lineHeight)
    };
};

alert(JSON.stringify($("div").textSize()));
```

```css
div {
    font-family: monospace;
    background: black;
    color: lightgreen;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to use `context.font = [$self.css('font-size'), $self.css('font-family')].join(' ');` to make it work for firefox as well (*`font` returns "" if not set on the same item*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks for suggestion. I updated it.

Comment: also keep in mind that you will not get exact results as bold/italic can also affect it and bold (font-weight) has varying levels. You would need to match all `font` properties (see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-font)

Answer (score -1):

You can not calculate how many character would fit in the div this way, `font-size:50px` does not define the width of each character (just compare "w" and "l", these character can not have the same width).

Try: [Finding how many letter div fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525408/finding-how-many-letter-div-fit)
And: http://itnow.blogspot.fr/2009/05/calculating-number-of-characters-that.html

Regards,

Comment: This is simply not correct.

Comment: @ZachSaucier can u explain?? Does font—size define the width of a character?

Comment: "You can not calculate how many character would fit in the div this way" - you can, as seen in the other answer. "font-size:50px does not define the width of each character " - it does, just not *the same* for each character.

Comment: Sorry I think I did not explain myself correctly, I mean you cannot calculate by juste divide the width of the div by the css property "font-size" value. And by "font-size:50px does not define the width of each character, I mean the width of each character is not "50px". Am I right? Maybe I misundertand the question...